# Lottery Machine Series Matching

Tags: combinatorics

Assume there is a lottery machine with 9 slots and 11 symbols (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K) with decreasing probabilities. In this case, the probabilities are:

```
[0.125,0.125,0.105,0.105,0.1,0.1,0.085,0.085,0.07,0.06,0.04]
```

respectively.

The symbols are randomly assigned to each slot on a spin and can be repeated.

```
(e.g. {A,D,A,G,I,J,K,A,A})
```

If three or more slots have the same symbol, the symbol is added to a output array, which can contain a maximum of 3 symbols (normal case).

```
(e.g. First spin: {A,D,A,G,I,J,K,A,A} ->  -> [A])
(     Second spin: {D,D,A,G,D,B,K,C,A} ->  -> [A,D])
```

If there two or more symbols are acquired from the same spin, all symbols are appended to the list.

```
(e.g Third spin: {A,D,F,D,F,F,A,A,D} ->  -> [A,D,A,D,F])
```

The list can only be extended if the "last" spin exceeds or equals to the size limit (3) of the list.

```
(e.g. First Spin: {A,D,F,D,F,F,A,A,D} ->  -> [A,D,F] -> *no more spins*
```

```
(e.g. First Spin: {B,C,C,B,B,B,B,C,B} ->  -> [B,C])
(     Second Spin: {K,K,K,J,A,A,C,J,J} ->  -> [B,C,J,K] -> *no more spins*)
```

Given that the player can only spin 3 times, and that order does not matter and for Length-4 or Length-5 sequences, as long as the string contains the three symbols, it is considered a match. How do I find the probability of the output array containing a specific Length-3 combination?

(e.g. For combination ADF, Some of the matching sequences are
ADF, DAF, FAD, AADF, ADAF, DAKAF, ABJDF)

Comment: Please be clear and precise in your descriptions.  What is a "specific combination" and how is it related to your example?  For instance, after the third spin, is the combination `ADADF` or is it `ADF`? Do you consider `ADF` to be the same as `AFD`?  Be aware that because the individual probabilities are arbitrary, the answers will either be long, nasty formulas or dynamic programs, which will lead us to wonder whether approximations would be acceptable and if so, how accurate do they need to be? Finally, please don't delete and repost your questions: that loses all previous comments.

Comment: Updated the vague parts once again. Either a formula or a way to program it would be nice, as I'd need the exact probabilities for each combination.